# After I ran Timer.periodic function and stopped it,but still I cant stop it from running in the console.I dont know what to do

Tags: flutter

I ran this code and later deleted it.After that no matter what an infinite loop printing in the console:

```
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
I/flutter ( 7472): Yeah, this line is printed 
...
...
```

keeps running.How do I stop this?

Code :

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
  print("Yeah this line is printed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this code is inside `StatefullWidget`

you can create field and start Timer e.g. from `initState` method like this

```
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      print("Yeah this line is printed");
    });
  }
```

then you can stop the timer

```
_timer.cancel();
```

Comment: Thank you.I figured it out myself later.Anyhow hope this will help someone